# Where does the quran mention us to reffer to hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith

I want to know if the quran mentions to us, if in doubt or need more clarity in quran reffer hadith. Please provide proof only from the quran. Thank you and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Please use the search feature to view related questions that have already been answered for example [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47886/i) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/) are relevant.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem
As sallamu alaykum wa rahmatullah wa baraktuhu

Allah سبحانه وتعالى says in surah 4vs 59

> "O those of you who have believed obey allah obey his messenger"
>
> “And whatever the Messenger gives you, take it, and whatever he forbids you, abstain. And have Taqwa of Allah. Verily Allah is severe in punishment.” [59:7]

So allah has ordered us to obey him and the messenger in the messenger صلى الله عليه وسلم now he has passed away صلى الله عليه وسلم we obey him by referring to his hadith.

Also allah has told us the prophet muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم sunnah makes the verses of Allah clear in surah nahl 16vs 44

> "We sent you with clear proofs and written ordinances. And We revealed to you the message that you may make CLEAR to the people what was sent down to them and that they might give thought.

So in summary Allah in quran orders us to refer to him which is quran and to his messenger who doesnt speak from his desire only revalation .

Allah knows best