# Does the Quran forbid hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith

I ask this because there are some verses in the quran that perhaps allude to the  rejection of hadith, such as:

45:6 "in which other hadith will they believe after God and his verses?"

6:38 "And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will be gathered.

7:52 "And We had certainly brought them a Book which We detailed by knowledge - as guidance and mercy to a people who believe"

Some of these quotes specifically mention that the Quran is fully detailed, i think this reasonably suggests that the common usage of hadith which is to complement and add to the quran is thus unacceptable, however there are other verses in the Quran which seem to suggest the opposite, for example:

16:44 "with clear proofs and written ordinances. And We revealed to you the message that you may make clear to the people what was sent down to them and that they might give thought."

Here,  god states Muhammad's purpose is to clarify the Quran, and I think this suggests that Hadith are necessary, because since Muhammad is dead and can no longer clarify the Quran, the hadith (his teachings) are the only way to benefit from Muhammad's teachings, and to affirm his position as a correct interpreter of the Quran and also the only one with the God given right to do this. I may be wrong, but i think it is important for there to be someone who holds a **correct** interpretation of the Quran, because the Quran can be interpreted in infinite many ways due to its apt use of metaphor.

Some clarification on both the verses and legitimacy of hadith is appreciated

Comment: A major part of your question is already addressed on the site, such as [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25922/20218) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47886/is-there-any-reason-to-not-follow-only-the-quran-and-reject-the-sunnah/47895#47895).

Comment: Where did you get this translation:

16:44 "with clear proofs and written ordinances. And We revealed to you the message that you may make clear to the people what was sent down to them and that they might give thought."

?

Comment: It is the Saheeh international translation, I found it on Quran.com.

Comment: @UbaidHassan The more precise translation of the ayah 16:44 would be:

"with clear proofs and written ordinances. And We revealed to you the Reminder (Remembrance - الذِّكْرَ) that you may make clear to the people what was sent down to them and that they might give thought."

Quran itself is called الذِّكْرَ - (reminder, remembrance), for example in ayah: 36:69

Comment: Quran definitely does not forbid all the hadiths. For example:

9. Has the story (حَدِيثُ - hadith) of Moses reached you?

10. When he saw a fire, he said to his family, “Stay; I have noticed a fire; Perhaps I can bring you a torch therefrom, or find some guidance by the fire.”

Suhar 29

Comment: @truthcures interesting point, but both the bible and Torah told story of Moses, how can I tell if God was referring to the stories he wrote in the holy books or the stories told by men(in that Quran verse you mentioned)

Comment: @UbaidHassan Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. Of course Bible tells the story of Moses, what's the problem?

45:6 "in which other hadith will they believe after God and his verses?" - it does not mean that hadiths inside the Quran are non trustworthy, quite the opposite.

Comment: @truthcures i should have been more clear, my bad. So you used the question "has the story of moses reached you?" said by God in the Quran to say that this shows that Hadeeth outside of the ones told in the holy books are permissible( i think u meant this). But since the bible and torah also tell the story of moses, we have no way of knowing if the **story** God was talking about in the quran verse you cited **Has the story of Moses reached you** was referring to the story God himself wrote in the holy books, **or** the story of moses that spread amongst people.

Comment: @Hisham Besides the already excellent answer given by "The Z", I would also like to mention that if you want to learn more regarding Qur'an and Hadith interpretation, please learn Arabic first. As we see here, you incorrectly interpreted the word "Hadith" in verse because of a "supposed" lack of knowledge in Arabic.

Comment: The legitimacy of the hadiths is a matter in which there is much dispute between certain Islamic schools. As-written, this will just attract opinions and arguments rather than bring any clarity to an already divisive issue.

Answer (score 4):

1.

> "These are the verses of Allah which We recite to you in truth. Then in what statement (hadith in Arabic) after Allah and His verses will they believe?" (45:6)

There are several problems with your understanding of this verse.

First, we can concentrate on the meaning of "hadith." Hadith means speech or statement. However, in Islamic contexts, it has come to mean hadith specifically of the Prophet (SAW). So, the verse is rhetorically asking "What other speech will you believe in after Allah and his verses."

But, it is not referring to the hadith of the Prophet (SAW) specifically nor any other hadith specifically either. And it is clear that it does not mean to be comprehensive in what is allowed to believe. For example, several places in the Quran tell us to believe in the angels. However, that is another hadith to believe in "after Allah and his verses." Is that forbidden by this verse? No, clearly not because the verse does not mean to be comprehensive in what can be believed.

More obviously, the verse is rhetorical. The "after" in the verse is meant figuratively not literally. This can be shown by the fact that neither the verses before or the verses after actually refer to people who believe in the Quran and then believe in something else. All of the verses are referring to people who don't believe in the Quran in the first place [*italics my comments explaining*]:

> **"These are the verses of Allah which We recite to you in truth." [...]** (45:6) *How does the Quran being true argue against those who believe in the hadith of others in addition to the Quran? They already believe the Quran is true. You would expect something saying "The Quran should be alone or the Quran is completely detailed if that was the intent.*
>
> **"Who hears the verses of Allah recited to him, then persists arrogantly as if he had not heard them. So give him tidings of a painful punishment."** (45:8) *Clearly referring to a person who rejects Allah's verses completely like the Kuffar of Makkah.*
>
> **"And when he knows anything of Our verses, he takes them in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment"** (45:9)
>
> **"This [Qur'an] is guidance. And those who have disbelieved in the verses of their Lord will have a painful punishment of foul nature."** (45:11) *Again referring to disbelief rather than belief in something else.*

So, the question is meant similar to "What thing are you going to believe after [foregoing] Allah and his verses?" And it is not meant to forbid believing anything else. Because if so, you would be forbidden from reading and believing any scholar. You would be forbidden from reading and believing any science. You would even be forbidden from believing this answer! But, that makes no sense. Clearly, you can find true things outside of Allah's verses and you can believe them. This verse is only a rhetorical question to those who disbelieve in Allah's verse on how they find anything else worth believing.

2.

> "And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will be gathered." (6:38)

This is not referring to the Quran and that is trivial to demonstrate. I can find a bird right now flying with its wings that is not mentioned in the Quran. This is referring instead to Allah's record and knowledge of everything. A similar verse mentioning this "register" or book is the following:

> "And there is no creature on earth but that upon Allah is its provision, and He knows its place of dwelling and place of storage. All is in a clear register." (6:11)

3.

> "And We had certainly brought them a Book which We detailed by knowledge - as guidance and mercy to a people who believe" (7:52)

The question here is not whether the Quran is detailed with knowledge to be a guidance because everyone agrees to that. But, nowhere in the Quran does it say that the Prophet is not a source of guidance. In fact, repeatedly, Allah mentions the Prophet (SAW) as the second most important belief after Himself.

---

The Quran is clear on the matter of obeying the Prophet (SAW). The Quran says:

"He who obeys the Messenger has obeyed Allah ; but those who turn away - We have not sent you over them as a guardian." (4:80)

What is made clear is that when the messenger explains something or proscribes something as part of the religion it is a part of revelation from God, since God taught the messenger.