# Can Imams abrogate Quran?

Tags: shiism, shia-imam, imamah, naskh, shia-ismaili

Do Shi'as believe that the words of the Imams can abrogate the Quran? In what circumstances can this happen?

If infallible Muhammad can abrogate the Quran with his own words, as many Sunnis believe, than that implies that the Imams can do the same, as they are also infallible.

How do Twelvers and Ismailis differ on this question?

Comment: Can you give an example of when Mohamed pbuh abrogated the Quran with his own wording?

Comment: @AbduRahman Looking at this it seems that some Sunnis believe that Sunnah can abrogate Quran: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/73208/can-sunnah-abrogate-quran

Answer (score 1):

Can imams abrogate the Quran?
Abrogation by the imams happens if this ruling is from God and the prophet told the imam, otherwise, the imams cannot issue the ruling of abrogation on their own behalf.
Abrogation is one of the concepts of legislation. Legislation is only for God, and the rulings came to the Prophet through revelation, and the Prophet cannot legislate a ruling on his own behalf. The same is true for the imams, and the imams cannot issue a ruling on their own behalf.
https://pasokhgo.valiasr-aj.com/porseman/showquestion.php?code=3548